# Duplicate entries in Windows 7 Boot Manager

Tags: windows-7, boot, wim

I have problem when with Boot Manager. When I restore System with using *.wim file after restart I see two identical entries. Booth entries run the same System. How I can remove this ? Of course I know so I can run msconfig->>boot and then remove one. But how remove this for *wim image?

Please give me some advice.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use easyBCD boot manager to remove any entry you don't need:

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Comment: Can I remove this entries with usuage some vbscript or batch ?

Answer (score 0):

[Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) displays exact path for every loader so you can delete the loader you don't need.

The tool gives access to every property of a loader and boot manager so you can fine tune the behavior of the applications.